# Python/Sqlite3 - SELECT statement from an item in a for looped list

Tags: python, sql, database, list, sqlite

I have 2 sqlite3 databases with 2 different tables, I will refer to table from database 1 as DB-A, and table from database 2 as DB-B.

DB-A stores rows with fields: Username, Date Recorded, Selection

DB-B stores rows with 20 fields, from which Date Recorded, Selection have equivalent fields (slightly different format).

format difference example: DB-A:Date Record format is DD-MM-YYYY
DB-B:Date Record format is YYYY-MM-DD

format difference example: DB-A:Selection includes spaces and hyphens,
DB-B:Selection is all lowercase no spaces or hyphens.

I am currently doing a SELECT * from DB-A where Username = ?       (user defined username)
and .fetchall() it to a list: userList.

I then have a for loop with the following pseudocode

```
for item in userList:
    reformat item['Date Record']
    reformat item['Selection']
    SELECT * from DB-B:Table WHERE DB-B:Date Record = item['Date Record'] AND DB-B:Selection like item['Selection]

     execute logic here based on select.fetchall()
```

Now the code works, however this takes forever (9hours+ sometimes) given my userList can be up to 14405 rows, and the DB-B has 3million+ rows.

Can anyone suggest a better way to approach this kind of problem to get a significantly lower execution time?

Appreciate any help,
Developed.

Comment: is there a particular reason they are not stored in the same database? this whole situation would be alleviated with a `join`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response aws_apprentice. No particular reason besides the poor structure I have (hobbyist programmer). Would the join still be useful given the Date Recorded, and Selection are formatted differently in the fields?

Comment: yes, you can convert and manipulate them within the database to match your needs, honestly this would be the most efficient way

Comment: Appreciate the response and insight. I will experiment with combining the tables to 1 database and using join.

Comment: @Developed if you plan to make changes to the design make sure that you always store dates in this format: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: You can `ATTACH` the second database to the first and use joins... Maybe with the aid of a python user defined SQL function to do the reformatting.

Comment: Basically you have a loop on a somewhat large table (DB-A) without taking advantage of any index, which means that the whole table DB-B has to be scanned every time to fetch the results. This a huge performance hit and probably a waste of electricity too. It would help if you could explain in more details what you're trying to achieve and show a schema of your tables.

Comment: @aws_apprentice Thanks mate, I got a satisfactory solution to my problem using join.